# Ionic 6 with React - no animation on page navigation

Tags: reactjs, ionic-framework

I'm building an Ionic React (using Ionic 6 and Capacitor) application.
I have two pages, `Home` and `Profile`.
I want to navigate between the home page and profile page, it is working but there is no push animation on the iOS simulator.

This is my Router (on App.tsx):

```
 <IonApp>
     <IonRouterOutlet>
      <IonReactRouter>
        <Route exact path="/home" component={Home} />
        <Route exact path="/profile" component={Profile} />
        <Route exact path="/" render={() => <Redirect to="/home" />} />
      </IonReactRouter>
    </IonRouterOutlet>
 </IonApp >
```

Home and Profile of course have `IonPage` as the root element.

```
return (
        <IonPage>
            ...
            ...
       </IonPage>
);
```

I use useIonRouter hook, like this:

```
 const router = useIonRouter();
 const displayProfile = () => {
    router.push('/profile', 'forward', 'push');
};
```

It does go to the Profile page, but with no animation at all.
I couldn't find anything but basic examples on their website for the this.

Comment: maybe this will help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58452159/ionic-react-4-11-how-to-push-and-pop-in-navigation-ionnav

Comment: @Callan Thank you, I read this before posting, and it does actually work, but  as I said, I don't see the animation being played.

Comment: Do you have a `IonRouterOutlet` in the Home and Profile pages?

Comment: @cascading-jox No, I copied the docs and I didn't see where they added it. I do have the RouterOutlet on the App.tsx

Comment: It's strange that not even the code examples from the docs work...

Comment: Have you found a solution ? I struggle with the same issue...

Answer (score -1):

[Per the official example](https://github.com/ionic-team/starters/blob/main/react/base/src/App.tsx#L1-L7), be sure to include the CSS

```
/* Core CSS required for Ionic components to work properly */
import '@ionic/react/css/core.css';

/* Basic CSS for apps built with Ionic */
import '@ionic/react/css/normalize.css';
import '@ionic/react/css/structure.css';
import '@ionic/react/css/typography.css';
```